# Validação de CheckBox em outro form

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá, pessoal.

Provavelmente minha dúvida é um pouco boba de mais, porém não encontrei muita coisa semelhante na internet...

Vocês poderiam me explicar melhor como eu consigo chamar o valor de um `CheckBox` para outro form?

A minha ideia é pegar informações pré-determinadas no nome da `checkBox`, e jogar elas no outro form, onde eu posso "validar" essas strings.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ela não é boba, mas ela também não está explicada direito. Mostre o que está tentando falar, dê detalhes do problemas, onde quer chegar, etc.

Comment: Esse projeto é web, certo? Ele é Web Forms ou ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Não, o projeto é Desktop local. Na verdade é um "jogo" em forma de texto pra galera de Informática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um botão OK e um evento para quando o usuário clicar nele, se a checkBox tiver marcada, ele vai colocar true em uma variável global do tipo boleano e depois é só colocar um If na outra Window para comparar

```
private void button_OK_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox.IsChecked == true) 
            MainWindow.Global.pergunta1 = true;
     }
```